# How to use mysql online with a desktop app

Tags: python, mysql

Is there any way to convert an app written with kivy, python to use an online mysql database, this is usually straight forward for web apps written in python, how about desktop apps written in platforms like kivy and Tkinter that want to use an online mysql database for data sharing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose you need a remote mysql server. A local mysql database will only take changes locally, within your computer, but a remote database, will accept data given to them from any device connected to it. There are paid and non paid websites that provide such hosting. Here are some free ones:

- [FreeMySQLHosting](https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/)
- [RemoteMySQL](https://remotemysql.com/)
- [FreeSQLdatabase](https://www.freesqldatabase.com/)
- [db4free](https://www.db4free.net/)

What you should be looking for is "remote" mysql databases because some online database wont allow you to write to it.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371718/how-to-give-permission-to-other-pc-to-add-data-to-my-database-in-mysql-in-my-com) answer for some explanation